# Show and Hide Active Chart

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code which allows charts to show and hide however i have too many charts and hardcoding each of it would be a great hassle. Thus is it possible to hide and show charts based on the active chart?

I have this code and i tried replacing the `Chartobjects("Chart4")` to `ActiveChart` but it says object does not support that property. Any alternative ways to make this happen or is there anything wrong with my code? Thank you in advance!

```
Sub ActiveChartShowHide()


With Sheets("Sheet4").ChartObjects("Chart 4")
.Visible = Not .Visible
End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveChart refers to the Chart object which is a member of the ChartObject object. Your code should be:

```
With ActiveChart.Parent
    .Visible = Not .Visible
End With
```

Comment: I am getting a "object variable or with block variable not set" error messgae

Comment: yup! I did activate it by clicking on it

Comment: Which line is giving you the error? Is your sheet protected by any chance?

Comment: It works when i want to hide but cant show it back:/

Comment: Yes it won't work because a hidden chart can't be the active chart. Do you want to make all charts visible again, or just a specific one?

Comment: That makes sense. I want to make specific ones. In that case i have to hardcode all the chart names to make it visible isit?

Comment: Probably. How else would the user select which chart to make visible? I guess one option would be to select a range that the chart is based on.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the chart objects to show or hide all of them to save time and typing:

```
Option Explicit

Sub HideAllChartsInSheet1()
    Dim oChartObject As ChartObject

    For Each oChartObject In Sheet1.ChartObjects
        oChartObject.Visible = False
    Next

    Set oChartObject = Nothing
End Sub
```

Replace `Sheet1` with a reference to your actual Worksheet-object, and of course use `oChartObject.Visible = True` to show the ChartObjects instead.

**EDIT**:
Let's change the sub to modify specific chart object:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChartVisible(psName As String, pbVisible As Boolean)
    Dim oChartObject As ChartObject

    For Each oChartObject In Sheet1.ChartObjects
        If UCase(oChartObject.Name) = UCase(psName) Then
            oChartObject.Visible = pbVisible
        End If
    Next

    Set oChartObject = Nothing
End Sub
```

Example: use the following to hide "Chart 4" on Sheet1:

```
Call ChartVisible("Chart 4", False)
```

Comment: I want to selectively hide and unhide charts

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. I have updated the answer, see if it is something you can use. I don't think you can use the Visible property with ActiveChart.

Comment: psName is supposed to be replaced with the chart name isit?

Comment: the programme runs but no charts do not become invisible

Comment: Yes, parameters are chart name and a boolean to decide if you want to show or hide it. Will add it to code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can just select your chart and then hide it:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
     Selection.Visible = false
```

Comment: But i still have to define the chart name. I want to activate the chart which the cursor is on.